# jQuery custom validation comparing the sequences of multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jQuery validate plugin to check whether or not the sequence of 3 date inputs (for example) is in ascending order. My approach is to write a loop which compares input dates from the top to the bottom (first check 1st and 2nd, then check 2nd and 3rd).

My question:

1. how many times do I need to apply this validation rule? Currently, I
   applied this rule to the first input. Though, it checked whether or
   not my 3 inputs are in sequence. The error messages always showed up
   next to the first input. No matter the location of the error.
2. should I modify the function into only compare itself inputs VS its successor, and apply it all of the inputs except the last one?

**update** A new question... If I go with question 2. I need to apply this validaton rule n-1 times for the necessary elements (I can also build a new class). My new question is how do I tell jQuery which which two dates should be compared (first check date 1 and date2, second time check date 2 and date 3)?
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/Ks2yr/18/)

HTML (a table form with three dates inputs)

```
<form id="form1"><table><tr class = "app_dates"><th><label for = "id_Date_apt"> Application Date 1 (MM/DD): </label></th> <td> <input id = "id_Date_apt" type = "text" value = "01/11" name = "Date_apt"/></td></tr>
<tr class = "app_dates"><th><label for = "id_Date_apt"> Application Date 2 (MM/DD): </label></th> <td> <input id = "id_Date_apt2" type = "text" value = "12/12" name = "Date_apt2"/></td></tr>
<tr class = "app_dates"><th><label for = "id_Date_apt"> Application Date 3 (MM/DD): </label></th> <td> <input id = "id_Date_apt3" type = "text" value = "03/13" name = "Date_apt3"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td></tr></table></form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //create a function used compare the sequence of input values
    function isDate() {
    var siz = $('input[id^="id_Date_"]').size()
    date = []
    temp_f = 0

// this for loop compares the secquences of application dates in pairs    
    for (var i = 0; i < siz - 1; i++) {
        j = i + 1
        var date1_m = parseFloat($('input[id^="id_Date_apt"]:eq(' + i + ')').val().slice(0, 2))
        var date2_m = parseFloat($('input[id^="id_Date_apt"]:eq(' + j + ')').val().slice(0, 2))
        var date1_d = parseFloat($('input[id^="id_Date_apt"]:eq(' + i + ')').val().slice(3, 5))
        var date2_d = parseFloat($('input[id^="id_Date_apt"]:eq(' + j + ')').val().slice(3, 5))
        var date1_full = new Date(1960, date1_m - 01, date1_d)
        var date2_full = new Date(1960, date2_m - 01, date2_d)

        if (date1_full > date2_full) {
            temp = 0
        }
        else {
            temp = 1
        }
        temp_f = temp_f + temp
    } //end of for loop

    if (temp_f != siz-1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

//validation////
$.validator.addMethod("dateFormat", function(value, element) {
    return isDate();
}, "Inputs are not in sequence");

$("#form1").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        SubmittingForm()
    },
    rules: {
        //should I add the validation rule for Date_apt2 and Date_apt3??    
        Date_apt: {
            dateFormat: true
        }
    }
})

})​
```

​

Comment: I'd say yes to question 2 for a more flexible system, but inverted.  Each should check the one before it as that would most likely align better with the flow of user interaction.  Then for question 1, that means you'd apply the logic whenever #2 or #3 changed (which again should be more intuitive).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is check each date against its predecessor. Since people usually fill in forms  from top down, I'd consider the *second* date in a pair to be the wrong when when they're out of order. But either way is fine.

You don't need to put an explicit rule for each date in the `.validate()` call. If you give a form element a class name that matches a validation method, the method will be called automatically. So just give all but the last or first `date_aptN` elements the class `dateFormat`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. If I go with question 2. I need to apply this validaton rule n-1 times for the necessary elements (I can also build a new class). My new question is how do I tell jQuery which which two dates should be compared (first check date 1 and date2, second time check date 2 and date 3)?

Comment: You don't need to do it N-1 times, the plugin automatically applies it to all the elements that match the class. Your custom validation method receives the element being validated as an argument. It can use `$(elem).closest("tr").prev().find(".dateClass").val()` to get the previous date so it can compare them.